# Can I download a copy of the site to browse offline?

Tags: support, data-dump

I am a student and avid reader of this site and I usually visit this site and read the questions and answers daily. Would it be possible to back up this site to my computer? I would like to have a copy for my personal reference, to browse questions and answers offline. Can I do this legally? How?

Comment: Why do you need a backup of the site? If you access it every day anyway, then this just works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no need for you to backup the site. SE have their own business continuity plans. You can access SE every day anyway, so I am not sure why you would need something copied locally **for personal reference.**

If you really **must** have a copy of the data, Stack Exchange Data Explorer publishes a data dump every three months, which you can freely use.

Have a look at [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/) on the topic, and for guidance on how to be notified of updates.

Comment: ok thanks i just thought to copy it for my reference when i am offline

Comment: You can use the data explorer dump if you must have an offline copy. It is also useful if you need to do any data mining.

Comment: Not everyone has a persistent high availability connection to the internet. In such cases, caching content for later reading is useful

Comment: Additionally, if he's using a UNIX-based system, recursive wget could be helpful. I mean, I wouldn't do it myself, partly out of respect for SE, and partly because that could lead to filling a lot of hard drive space in a very short period of time.